# With Android, how do I set the maximum deadline for a Cloud Endpoint request?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

When making a `ClientEndpoint` API request from an Android app to an App-Engine service, how do I set a deadline/timeout for the `execute()` action?

I'm looking for something like:

```
Foo foo = endpoint.getSomething(id) .setDeadline(2000/*ms*/) .execute();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When building the endpoint, specify a connect and read timeout in HttpRequestInitializer. For example, in this case 20 and 10 secs respectively.

```
SomeEndpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new SomeEndpoint.Builder(
    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
    new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) {
            httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(20 * 1000);
            httpRequest.setReadTimeout(10 * 1000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you're using the GoogleCredential object in your endpoint builder for authentication, you can set the custom timeout params as described in this link: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/errors

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if one can control that. Since the Endpoints are hosted in an App Engine environment, standard timeout for any App Engine HTTP Request should apply i.e. 60 seconds.

Comment: Theoretically, the client could choose to abort the request early.  But I can't find any way to do that so perhaps it's simply not supported.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You just need to implement your own HttpRequestInitializer where you set connect and read timeouts in its initialize method. This HttpRequestInitializer need to be passed then as a parameter to your endpoint builder constructor.