# Customed HTTP requests with Cloud Endpoints

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an API working with Cloud Endpoints and I added its generated client library to my Android app.

However I don't know how to add information to my requests. For now, here is the only HTTP request I know how to send using the client library:

```
DrinkEndpoint.Builder builder = new DrinkEndpoint.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),new GsonFactory(), null);
        DrinkEndpoint service = builder.build();
        Drink drink = new Drink();
        drink.setName(params[0]);
        response = service.insertDrink(drink).execute();
```

So my question is: how to modify this request to add information either in the headers or in the body of the request?
For instance, I want to add a String that is not an attribute of the Drink entity.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your `insertDrink(drink)` method returns a `InsertDrink` instance which is a child of `InsertDrinkEndpointRequest`.
The `InsertDrinkEndpointRequest` instance allows you to set the request header by calling the `setRequestHeaders(httpHeader)` method.
In your case: `service.insertDrink(drink).setRequestHeaders(httpHeader).execute()`.

This way of building a cloud endpoint request may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21492950/2205582